# android read/write user preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am migrating iOS app to android and, thinking about iOS, I set a default plist file with strings and keys that are then modified using NSuserDefaults. I read some posts and docs and not really clear about how to do it properly in Android. 
I need a preferences file with keys and strings that I could read and write. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences settings;
settings = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//get the sharepref
int id = settings.getInt("ID", 0);

//set the sharedpref
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("ID", "1");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Although a simple RTFM would be justified, I must admit to using your answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read Settings

```
public static String readSetting(Context context, String key, String defaul){
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mySettings",MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getString(key,defaul);
    }
```

save settings-

```
@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
public static void saveSetting(Context context, String key, String valu){
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mySettings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit= preferences.edit();
    edit.putString(key,valu);
    edit.commit();

}
```