# "global" array with different data types - Android

Tags: android, arrays, list

I'm new in programming for Android so maybe my question will be very easy to solve but still. I'm trying to make an array of different data types :

I have to add there :

> ```
>    int number
>    String name 
>    int number_2
>    int time
>    int total
> ```

And my question now is how to implement it in easiest way, and how to get data from it. In case that I have to get a different records for this variables and store it into list .

Also  have a question about way how to keep all values which I handle inside of my array. 
I have to keep it because in my program I have to go back to other activities go forward to another and again collect data and add it to my array.

What will be the best and easiest solution ?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

You could create the Array as an Array of Objects. All other classes are derived from `Object`, so you'll be able to store all types of objects in your Array. However, you would have to check the type of an object you get from the Array, before you'd be able to safely interpret as an object of a specific class. Moreover, you would have to use Integer instead of int.

If all (or at least multiple) of your elements you are intending to store in the Array are belonging to one (physical) entity, you could create a custom `Class` that holds its own properties as class members, and fill your Array with a list of instances of this `Class`.

Moreover, if you plan to add elements to your Array, you should use a `List` instead, e.g. an `ArrayList`.

As for retaining your data, you would have to either store it in a database, or save it to a file. In either way, you will have to save it upon close of the Activity, and load it again once the Activity starts

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data across activities you will need to pass them using objects you can store in an intent. Seems like the best way to handle that is to either create a PREFS file to store the data or to create an object that extends Parcelable like here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593619/android-parcelable-object-passing-to-another-activity

Parcelables are preferable assuming you need all the data in a single object, you do not want to "putExtra" a bunch of fields and you also want to be sure data can pass from one activity to another. Otherwise, a simple Util class that reads and writes to a PREFS file is the way to go:

[android read/write user preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498713/android-read-write-user-preferences)

A database is always another option, but seems well outside the scope of your question.